# Prestashop webservice get features in one request

Tags: php, xml, prestashop, product

I am using Prestashop's webservice, and I am trying to get products and product_feature_value's name in one request.

It's no problem getting the product_feature_value's names in another quest, but that is adding up 2-3 seconds for each product.

I have tried to achive it by using following code, with the option display=>full:

```
$webService = new \PrestaShopWebservice($this->path, $this->auth, $this->debug);
$xml = $webService->get(array(
'resource' => 'products',
'display' => 'full',
'filter[id_category_default]' => '[12|19|24|26]',
'filter[active]' => '[1]',
// 'limit' => 5,
'active' => '1'
));
$resource = $xml->children()->children();
return $resource;
```

However, it does not return the product_feature_value's names, only the id's.

Comment: I think is not possible to get all the product object in a query filtered, you need call again api with the specific product id, this way will return all the info about the product.

Comment: I was fearing the same thing, so I ended up creating my own script, and ditched the api due to heavy load :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can process data you got in `products` resource web service and append product features name and value accordingly.

You can do something like below;

```
$xml = $webService->get(array(
    'resource' => 'products',
    'display' => 'full',
    'filter[id_category_default]' => '[12|19|24|26]',
    'filter[active]' => '[1]',
    // 'limit' => 5,
    'active' => '1'
));

foreach ($xml->products->product as $product) {
    foreach ($product->associations->product_features->product_feature as $feature) {
        $featureName = $webService->get(array(
            'resource' => 'product_features',
            'id' => $feature->id,
        ));
        $featrueValue = $webService->get(array(
            'resource' => 'product_feature_values',
            'id' => $feature->id_feature_value
        ));
        $feature->feature_name = $featureName->product_feature->name->language->__toString();
        $feature->feature_value = $featrueValue->product_feature_value->value->language->__toString();
    }
}

$resource = $xml->children()->children();
return $resource;
```

Added `feature_name` and `feature_value`; see below result for reference which was added in `products` data.

```
[product_features] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [nodeType] => product_feature
                [api] => product_features
            )

        [product_feature] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [id] => 5
                        [id_feature_value] => 5
                        [feature_name] => Compositions
                        [feature_value] => Cotton
                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [id] => 6
                        [id_feature_value] => 11
                        [feature_name] => Styles
                        [feature_value] => Casual
                    )

                [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [id] => 7
                        [id_feature_value] => 17
                        [feature_name] => Properties
                        [feature_value] => Short Sleeve
                    )

            )

    )
```

Hope this will help you!